# redirect to another page when clicking to jquery popup button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used jquery popup to show the messages in my webpage.Now I want to redirect to another page when clicking button of jquery popup.I dont know how to do that.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup(message) {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").html(message);
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "Mandirdarsan Warning",
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('ok');
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });
        });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ok: function () {
  window.location="newurl";
}
```